# Where/when did Stephen Kleene first define the Kleene closure/star?

Tags: formal-languages, reference-request, automata

I'm working on a paper and would like to review the origins of [Kleene's closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star). I am unable to find any article of Kleene's that has the original definition of the Kleene closure.

Is there a paper by Kleene in which he first defines the Kleene closure?

Comment: Kleene, Stephen C. (1956). "Representation of Events in Nerve Nets and Finite Automata". In Shannon, Claude E.; McCarthy, John. Automata Studies. Princeton University Press. pp. 3–42.

Comment: (From the wikipedia page about Regular Expressions, I have never seen the paper, so don't know if it's exactly the right one.)

Comment: "If E and F are events already constructed, then by E*F we shall mean the event which consists of zero or more consecutive occurrences of E preceded by one of F." ... "The reason we do not define E* separately as ..." http://www.rand.org/pubs/research_memoranda/RM704.html (Rand 1951 Research Memorandum). @Wandering Logic can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kleene's classic paper on finite automata and regular expressions is

> Kleene, Stephen C.: "Representation of Events in Nerve Nets and Finite Automata". In Shannon, Claude E.; McCarthy, John. *Automata Studies*, Princeton University Press. pp. 3–42., 1956.

There seems to be a scan or recreation of that version of the paper at: http://www.dlsi.ua.es/~mlf/nnafmc/papers/kleene56representation.pdf.

But, as pointed out by @HendrickJan, the work seems to have been done about 5 years earlier.  The article starts with a note that says that "the material ... is drawn from Project RAND Research Memorandum RM-704 (15 Dec 1951, 101 pages) ... used by permission of the RAND Corporation ... supported by the RAND Corporation during the summer of 1951."  A scan of the RAND research memorandum is available for free from the RAND website: http://www.rand.org/pubs/research_memoranda/RM704.html.

"Regular events" are defined in Section 7 of both papers.  (page 46 of the 1951 memorandum and page 23 of the 1956 paper).  Interestingly, Kleene defines $*$, the closure operator, as a *binary* operator, rather than a unary operator as we do today.  This enables Kleene to avoid dealing with empty strings.  $E*F$ means the same thing it does today: "0 or more instances of E followed by F" but there is no way to say $E^*$ and have it include the empty string.

Comment: I'm imagining at some point later in the 50s, someone adapted it to the familiar unary version and attributed it to Kleene. Any idea where that happens?